# Finding trending, hot topic using Z-score

Tags: algorithm, information-retrieval

I am developing a system to finding trending, hot topic base on Z-score(standard score) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score.

I stuck in a problem:

Ex: i have 2 topic:

- topic 1:

  +day 1: 10 interaction

  +day 2: 20 interaction

  +day 3: 20 interaction

  +day 4: 20 interaction
- topic 2:

  +day 1: 100 interaction

  +day 2: 200 interaction

  +day 3: 200 interaction

  +day 4: 200 interaction

I use Z-score to calculate score z in day 4 for 2 topic, problem show here:

if i divide 2 data interaction for each topic, z-score of 2 topic almost same(0,66)(i mean i use 10,20,20,20 interaction for topic 1, 100,200,200,200 interaction for topic 2)

But i so confused, it is right way Z-score work or i must included all data interaction to calculate

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply all scores in one topic to get the scores for another topic (in your case topic 2 scores are all 10 times the topic 1 scores), then the z-score for day 4 you compute will be the same for both topics. In any event, if you want to consider each topic separately to find significant "hot" days for one topic, then the Student's t distribution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution is a much better way to go than simple z-score because t-distribution takes bias in estimating standard deviation properly into account, based on the number of samples.